# Image and Title with pagination via DataTables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

Is it possible to customise the paging control to below?

1 Every link has a title attribute, like "Go to page 5"

2 Using image icon, not text, for Next/Last/Previous/First

[image]

Any idea?

**Update**

Please the example below with solution to image issue

http://live.datatables.net/oxudak/48/edit

Please feel free to provide a better solution to the image issue, if any.

I am still looking for an attribute solution.

Comment: Hello. Where is your code? What have you tried? A snippet would be great, if you're able to reproduce the image without the title attribute I'll gladly take a look!

Comment: Thanks in advance. Please see my updated OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, you just need to write your jQuery code inside the `drawCallback` :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myTable = $("#example").DataTable({
    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
    "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"p>',
    "pageLength": 2,
    language: {
      paginate: {
        first: '«',
        previous: '‹',
        next: '<img style="width:15px;height:auto" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/praveen/minimal-outline/256/next-icon.png" />',
        last: '»'
      }
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    drawCallback: function() {
      $('.paginate_button').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text(),
          title = isNaN(text) ? text + ' page' : 'Page ' + text;
        $(this).attr('title', title);
      });
    }
  });
  $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 8;
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Russell Chavez</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzbd951x/